# Why does the mingw g++ compiler result in wrong linking result?

Tags: gcc, linker, mingw

I have some (larger) code developped under linux. Once I realized I would need it under windows I installed a cross compiler under linux and all went well.

Now the code should be managed futher without the need of the virtual machine. Therefore I installed mingw and tried to compile the code under windows.
I get a DLL without any warnings or similar.

But:
As soon as I tried to use the DLL (bind it in Matlab) I get an error about a module that could not be found. Using Dependency walker I get an error about

```
At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
```

I saw, that e.g. the function `InterlockedDecrement` from the kernel32.dll is red (missing). In the mingw installation I find a libkernel32.a that has two functions according to this function (output from `nm`):

```
00000000 T _InterlockedDecrement@4
00000000 I __imp__InterlockedDecrement@4
```

That looks quite good so far. In `c:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll` there is a function `InterlockedDecrement` according to `pexport`.

So my question is: Where is this error coming from? What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you use the dll outside of Matlab? Would you need to load kernel32.dll manually? (Thus would be very counterintuitive though)

Comment: It seems to work. I just tried one function but this one compiled and ran well.

Comment: Everything's the same bitness right? You're not mixing a 32-bit DLL with a 64-bit Matlab or anything?

Comment: Matlab is 32 bit. I think (and I am quite sure) that mingw only is able to translate to 32 bit natively. I did not use the mingw64 port. Also `gcc -dumpmachine` tells me `mingw32`. Seems to be 32 bit. I tested with this configuration both on 32 and on 64 bit machines.

Comment: OK. FYI, MinGW-w64 (mingw64 does not exist) is not a "port". It's a seperate project that extends and improves a lot on MinGW.org, providing both x86 and x64 toolchains. On-topic: Can you run the program through a debugger? Does the problem occur with MSVC as well or can you not test the code with that compiler? Matlab only officially supports MSVC, so you may be out of luck `:/`.